# An error when using a feed-forward neural network from the "forecast" package

Tags: r, time-series

I've got the following error when using the `nnetar` function from the `forecast` package:

> Error in rowMeans(sapply(fit, predict)) : 
>    'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
>   Called from: rowMeans(sapply(fit, predict))

But there is no error when I take the same input data and run the `nnetar` function line by line (I can do it since its source is available). Could you help me to understand the reason behind the error, please?

Code to reproduce the error:

```
library("forecast")

x <- structure(c(75.4076478, 74.77923336, 74.27204018, 73.47822515, 
            73.29823134, 72.91366804, 73.26790178, 74.09299464, 74.95585689, 
            75.43382793, 77.15040162, 78.22886226, 78.30629811, 78.79626749, 
            78.58930659, 77.3918156, 76.9386785, 76.39462267, 75.96094635, 
            75.20484764, 73.75982041, 73.37559835, 73.28544776, 72.63796541
), .Tsp = c(1, 1.95833333333333, 24), class = "ts")

nnetar(x, p = 6)
```

Session info:

> ```
> R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] forecast_8.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>  [1] Rcpp_0.12.9       quadprog_1.5-5    lattice_0.20-33   zoo_1.7-14        lmtest_0.9-35    
>  [6] assertthat_0.1    grid_3.3.0        plyr_1.8.4        gtable_0.2.0      magrittr_1.5     
> [11] scales_0.4.1      ggplot2_2.2.1     lazyeval_0.2.0    tseries_0.10-40   fracdiff_1.4-2   
> [16] timeDate_3012.100 tools_3.3.0       munsell_0.4.3     parallel_3.3.0    colorspace_1.3-2 
> [21] nnet_7.3-12       tibble_1.2
> ```

Comment: This works for me: nnetar(as.numeric(x), p=6)

Comment: This works for me too, thank you. It's still unclear why it doesn't work when  the input is a `ts` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the seasonality. `nnetar()` by default tries to include one seasonal lag with a seasonal series. So it tries to use a lag of 24 in this case, yet the series is only 24 observations long, so there is no data left to train.

Using `nnetar(as.numeric(x), p=6)` circumvents the problem by stripping off the ts attributes so `nnetar` no longer knows that the data is seasonal.

A cleaner way to do it would be `nnetar(x, p=6, P=0)`.

I've updated the function on [github](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/) so it tests for short series now and does not include the seasonal lag if there is insufficient data.